# Is there a Windows equivalent to the Unix uniq?

Tags: windows, sorting, uniq

I need remove duplicate lines from a text file, it is simple in Linux using

```
cat file.txt |sort | uniq
```

when file.txt contains

```
aaa
bbb
aaa
ccc
```

It will output

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Is there a Windows equivalent? or how do this in a Windows way?

Comment: On Unix, you could write it as `sort -u file.txt`

Comment: There is also WSL which works pretty well as far as this sort of stuff goes

Comment: Maybe you want to set something as solution, if you don't have any further questions?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `Sort-Object` cmdlet in PowerShell supports a `-Unique` switch that does the same thing as `uniq`:

```
Get-Content file.txt | Sort-Object -unique
```

Of course, owing to presence of aliases in PowerShell, you can also write:

```
type file.txt | sort -unique
```

Additionally, there is an undocumented `/unique` switch in `sort.exe` of Windows 10, so, this should work in Command Prompt:

```
type file.txt | sort /unique
```

Comment: I don't think the Windows command (`sort.exe`) supports this; it looks like a feature of the PowerShell builtin.

Comment: type unsorted.txt | sort -unique > sorted.txt
This really work under win10 and writed unique values to new file

Comment: @BenVoigt surprisingly, `type file.txt | sort /unique` works with _undocumented_ switch `/unique` of `sort.exe` utility (at least on Windows 10). On the other side, you are right that provided example is  PowerShell `Get-Content file.txt | Sort-Object -unique`, in fact.

Comment: @Lixas `type unsorted.txt | sort -unique` returns `-uniqueThe system cannot find the file specified` with errorlevel `1` if run from an open `cmd` prompt under Windows 10!

Comment: `sort /unique` errors with `Invalid switch.` on Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: @JosefZ , the answer specifies the switch using "/" (forward-slash) and not dash; the forward-slash is Windows standard for commands in CMD, and not all commands allow substituting a dash for a slash on command switches. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands for a quick reference consistently shows slashes. The above was a great answer, sharing a tidbit not commonly known, though I can't imagine why the "/unique" switch is undocumented since it's so useful.

Comment: @Debra sure. Microsoft said in their [archived _Windows NT Command Shell_ article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc723564(v=technet.10)): _command switches always begin with a slash `/` character… Occasionally, switches begin with a `+` or `-` character._

Comment: Ummm, yes, thank you Microsoft for stating "always", well, except when not so.

Comment: well what it file it's for example over 1 gb  ?

Comment: @JosefZ Well, I opened a [bug](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/issues/3858) for that, and now it *is* [documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sort) 

Comment: @TsahiAsher Great! Would be even better (discoverable) if `/?` would show it...

Answer (score 6):

There's ports of uniq that work identically to the gnu/coreutils versions. I personally use the variation from [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) but git for windows has a significantly [newer version](http://git-scm.com/download/win). No cygwin required though for the latter you need to look in /usr/bin

Since these packages also contain cat, sort and uniq - your workflow should be mostly identical, and `cat file.txt |sort | uniq` should work mostly identically

Answer (score 2):

You can easily write the command "uniq" by yourself. Save this in a batch file "uniq.cmd" somewhere in your %path% can find it (e.g. in %windir%\system32). This version is NOT case sensitive:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "prev="
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('sort %*') do (
    rem "set" needs to be done without delayed expansion
    set "line=%%F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:<=<!"
        if /i "!prev!" neq "!line!" echo(!line!
        set "prev=!line!"
    endlocal
)
```

This works with "uniq mytextfile" as well as "cat mytextfile | uniq"; as all input and arguments are simply passed to the sort command.

Starting with Windows 7, you may want a really case sensitive version (the difference ist undocumented switch "sort /C" and no "if /i"):

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "prev="
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('sort /C %*') do (
    rem "set" needs to be done without delayed expansion
    set "line=%%F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:<=<!"
        if "!prev!" neq "!line!" echo(!line!
        set "prev=!line!"
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Nice, but it has some flaws. It currently fails with content like `/?`, `ON`, `one ^ caret` or `bang!`. But that can be solved by using the [toggling delayed expansion technic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31133848/463115) and `echo(` see: [Dostips: ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554)

Comment: Thanks, the reason for using the toggling delayed expansion technic had not been obvious nor marked. I edited my examples to be (almost) perfect now.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to [Yu Jiaao's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1316321/165849). You can invoke the [`sort-object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) powershell cmdlet in a command prompt like:

```
type file.txt | powershell -nop "$input | sort -unique"
```